# How to send message to all the members of the group on Installing teams bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have created a teams bot and had a service written in .NET core to  handle events and user's messages to reply accordingly.

When I install a bot in a group, I need to send personal message(one-to-one i.e between bot and the user) to all the members of that group on installation. I am trying to do that in *OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync* event handler (which gets fired when I install the bot). But in this event I am getting information of the user who is installing the bot, not the other members which are added in that group, also I am not getting any information of the channel(channelId and members etc.) in which the bot is getting installed.

Any different approach or solution will work.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said if you want the bot to message the users privately (like 1-1 between the bot and user) or just send each person a personal message inside the group chat, but in both cases, Proactive Messaging is your correct approach. If you want to send a message inside the group chat itself, see [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs).

If you want to send the users messages directly, 1-1, they need to have the bot installed as a personal app already. It's possible to do this automatically, but it's a bit more work, and requires Microsoft Graph. The proactive messaging is a bit different too - you get the list of members as per the previous sample, but see [here](https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/teams-dev-samples/tree/add-proactive-messaging-sample/samples/bot-proactive-messaging) for how to get the required 1-1 conversation details, and how to send the actual message. This last link also has documentation on how to get started, and some background reading (at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

@Hilton is correct, You need to specify in which scope you want to notify user 1:1 or directly in Group chat?
App should be installed in user scope if notifying user on installation, You can [proactively install the App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp) in User/Group Chat/ team scope using Graph API. To notify users in Teams or Group chat, You can fetch the list of members using [List conversation members API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), When you install the App using Graph API Bot received converstionUpdate, You can save the conversationReference and use it for proactively notifying.